# How to create a ListView with a static image size Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a list which Works fine, but when i bind with a large image it not fill's the entire image box size that i set to 100x100, how to create a image size that could be able to adapt to any resolution ?

xaml Code :

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="2" SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="item" x:Name="listView">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Image WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" Source="{Binding image}"/>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="{Binding title}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding subtitle}" />
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The Result : 
[image]

Even if i put to 100x100 the image did not complete fill the entire box!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Image` control has property `Aspect` which defines how the image is filled to the frame.

1. **AspectFill** - Scale the image to fill the view. Some parts may be clipped in order to fill the view.
2. **AspectFit** - Scale the image to fit the view. Some parts may be left empty (letter boxing).
3. **Fill** - Scale the image so it exactly fill the view. Scaling may not be uniform in X and Y.

> [Aspect](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Image.Aspect/) - Gets or sets the scaling mode for the image. This is a
>   bindable property.

Use `Fill` if you want to fill the view.

Comment: Thanks, it Works, i have one more question, when i select a item, i have a color selection beneath of each image, that could be a margin problem? thanks.

Comment: You might be setting the background color, and underneath what you see is the native selected item color, either set selection color to transparent or not use background color in your item template.